# How to increase test coverage in salesforce for external api callout

Tags: json, api, salesforce

I have an apex class in which I am getting lots of count from external API.

External API returns results in JSON format. For decode this JSON I am using is the following code

```
ddDashboard obj = (ddDashboard) System.JSON.deserialize(json, ddDashboard.class);
```

Here `ddDashboard` is my class name.
Using this I am getting counts and I am directly assigning this count to class variable.

```
account_total_processed_records_count= obj.account_total_processed_records_count;
```

Here if I write this assignment then `test coverage` is decreased in APEX test result.

Anybody can help me how can I increase test coverage for above problem OR how can I write test method for assigning count value to class variable from external API call.

Answer (score 3):

You can test callouts using the mockinterfaces provided by the force.com framework or loading data from static resources. Actually running a callout from test context is not possible (and not really desired).

Have a look at the documentation about this:

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_restful_http_testing.htm